# Weak containment of unitary representations and group $C^*$-algebras

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. In order to make things simpler, let us say it is discrete. Let $\pi$ and $\rho$ be unitary representations of $G$ on Hilbert spaces $H_\pi$ and $H_\rho$ respectively. Let $C^*_\pi(G)$, resp. $C^*_\rho(G)$ be the corresponding group $C^*$-algebras, i.e. the $C^*$-algebras generated by $\{\pi(g): g\in G\}\subseteq B(H_\pi)$, and analogously for $\rho$.

It seems to be a folklore fact that the following two facts are equivalent

- $\rho\prec \pi$, i.e. $\rho$ is weakly contained in $\pi$;
- the map $\pi(g)\to\rho(g)$ extends to a ${}^*$-homomorphism from $C^*_\pi(G)$ onto $C^*_\rho(G)$; or equivalently, for every $x\in \mathbb{C}G$, $\|\pi(x)\|_{B(H_\pi)}\geq \|\rho(x)\|_{B(H_\rho)}$.

It looks quite clear on the first sight, however when trying to write down a precise proof, I get stuck.

I would be grateful for either writing down the proof or providing a reference where this is proved exactly as stated.

Comment: Check the "Equivalence Theorem" in section VII.5 of "Fell, J. M. G.; Doran, R. S._, Representations of *-algebras, locally compact groups, and Banach *- algebraic bundles. Vol. 1: Basic representation theory of groups and algebras,  ZBL0652.46050".

Answer (score 3):

The result is Theorem 7 in de la Harpe's paper "On simplicity of Reduced $C^*$-Algebras of Groups" ([here is a link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509450)).  The proof is skimmed there, and the details are not hard to fill in.

Comment: Thanks. But sorry for being dense but in the "negation of (iii) implies negation of (i)" I either miss something about double duals of $C^*$-algebras or in the worse case, even about the Hahn-Banach theorem. How does he find that $x\in C^*_{\mathrm{max}}(G)$? By Hahn-Banach I would find such $x$ in the double dual, not in $C^*(G)$.

Comment: No worries.  In this argument, the weak-$*$-topology is on $(C^*_{max}(G))^*$, the dual space of $C^*_{max}(G)$.  With this topology, every continuous linear functional on $C^*_{max}(G)^*$ is given by evaluation at some $x\in C^*_{max}(G)$.